# Como redimensionar una imagen en el canvas sin que pierda calidad React tsx

Tags: reactjs

Necesito redimensionar una imagen el el canvas para editarla, pero he notado que cuando lo hago y la muestro en el canvas se le baja la calidad a la iamgen, y lo he abierto con otros editores de imagenes y se rescala sin perder la calidad, que deberia hacer para hacer un perfecto rescalado de la imagen, ya lo intente mandadando la imagen a una api en python y ocupar opencv para rescalar la imagen, pero continua con cierta perdida en la calidad de la imagen, lo que hace esto es resetCanvasSize(), hay dos enfoques uno que lo hace con la api de python, y la que esta en comentarios es la que lo hace directamente en el navegador

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ModalContext } from './context/ModalProvider';

interface CanvasComponentState {
  dimensions: {
    width: number;
    height: number;
  };
}

interface CanvasImageProps {
  dimensions: {
    width: number;
    height: number;
  };
}

class CanvasImage extends Component<CanvasImageProps, CanvasComponentState> {
  static contextType = ModalContext;
  private prevImage: File | null = null;
  declare context: React.ContextType<typeof ModalContext>;

  private canvasRef: React.RefObject<HTMLCanvasElement>;

  constructor(props: CanvasImageProps) {
    super(props);
    this.canvasRef = React.createRef<HTMLCanvasElement>();
    this.state = {
      dimensions: {
        width: props.dimensions.width,
        height: props.dimensions.height
      }
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.prevImage = this.context!.image;
    this.resetCanvasSize();
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    const { image } = this.context!;
    
    if (image !== this.prevImage) {
      this.resetCanvasSize();
      this.prevImage = image;
    }
  }
  

  
  // ... tus importaciones y setup ...

resetCanvasSize = async () => {
  const { image } = this.context!;
  if (image instanceof Blob) {
      const img = new Image();
      img.onload = async () => {
          const maxWidth = this.props.dimensions.width - 10;
          const maxHeight = this.props.dimensions.height - 10;
          const canvasAspectRatio = maxWidth / maxHeight;
          const imgAspectRatio = img.width / img.height;
          let newWidth:number, newHeight:number;

          if (imgAspectRatio > canvasAspectRatio) {
              newWidth = maxWidth;
              newHeight = maxWidth / imgAspectRatio;
          } else {
              newHeight = maxHeight;
              newWidth = maxHeight * imgAspectRatio;
          }

          this.setState({ dimensions: { width: newWidth, height: newHeight } }, async () => {
              const formData = new FormData();
              formData.append('width', newWidth.toString());
              formData.append('height', newHeight.toString());
              formData.append('file', image);

              const response = await fetch('http://8000/api/imageRedimensionation', {
                  method: 'POST',
                  body: formData,
              });

              const blob = await response.blob();
              const objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

              const resizedImage = new Image();
              resizedImage.onload = () => {
                  const canvas = this.canvasRef.current;
                  console.log("imgWIDTH"+resizedImage.width+"imgHEIGHT:"+resizedImage.height)
                  if (canvas) {
                      canvas.width = resizedImage.width;
                      canvas.height = resizedImage.height;
                      console.log("WIDTH"+canvas.width+" heigth: w"+canvas.height)
                      const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
                      if (ctx) {
                          //ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = true;
                          //ctx.imageSmoothingQuality = 'high';  // Utilizar calidad alta para el escalado
                          ctx.clearRect(0, 0, resizedImage.width, resizedImage.height);
                          ctx.drawImage(resizedImage, 0, 0, resizedImage.width, resizedImage.height);
                      }
                  }
                  URL.revokeObjectURL(objectURL);
              };
              resizedImage.src = objectURL;
          });
      };
      img.src = URL.createObjectURL(image);
  } else {
      console.error("La imagen proporcionada no es un Blob o File");
  }
};

/*
resetCanvasSize = async () => {
  const { image } = this.context!;
  if (image instanceof Blob) {
    const img = new Image();
    img.onload = () => {
      const maxWidth = this.props.dimensions.width;
      const maxHeight = this.props.dimensions.height;
      const canvasAspectRatio = maxWidth / maxHeight;
      const imgAspectRatio = img.width / img.height;
      let newWidth:number, newHeight:number;

      if (imgAspectRatio > canvasAspectRatio) {
        // La imagen es más ancha que el canvas
        newWidth = maxWidth;
        newHeight = maxWidth / imgAspectRatio;
      } else {
        // La imagen es más alta que el canvas
        newHeight = maxHeight;
        newWidth = maxHeight * imgAspectRatio;
      }

      // Ahora actualiza el estado y dibuja la imagen en el canvas
      this.setState({ dimensions: { width: newWidth, height: newHeight } }, () => {
        const canvas = this.canvasRef.current;
        if (canvas) {
          canvas.width = newWidth;
          canvas.height = newHeight;
          console.log("WIDTH: "+canvas.width+" HEIGHT : "+canvas.height)
          const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
          if (ctx) {
            ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = true;
            ctx.imageSmoothingQuality = 'high'; // Asegurarse de que la calidad de la imagen sea alta
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
          }
        }
      });
    };
    img.src = URL.createObjectURL(image);
  } else {
    console.error("La imagen proporcionada no es un Blob o File");
  }
};
*/

  render() {
    const { width, height } = this.state.dimensions;
    return (
      <canvas
        ref={this.canvasRef}
        style={{
          width: `${width}px`,
          height: `${height}px`
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}

CanvasImage.contextType = ModalContext;

export default CanvasImage;
```